# May be error in enclosed text which has TEXT datatype in last column, MySQL Error 1064 occurs

Tags: mysql, syntax-error, mysql-workbench

I am getting the following error in the SQL query below.what can be the possible cause?

```
MySQL Error 1064:

You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near ''All rights reserved.\nRedistribution and use in source and binary forms, with o' at line 1
```

-- Table definition --

```
CREATE TABLE `licensetext_table` (
  `LicenseId` varchar(45) NOT NULL,
  `FullName` varchar(45) DEFAULT NULL,
  `OSI Approved` char(1) DEFAULT NULL,
  `License_Text` text,
  PRIMARY KEY (`LicenseId`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
```

---

**SQL Query**

```
INSERT INTO `test`.`licensetext_table` (`LicenseId`,`Full name`,`OSI Approved`,`License_Text`) 
VALUES ('BSD-2-Clause','BSD 2-clause \"Simplified\" License','Y','All rights reserved.\nRedistribution and use in source and binary forms, with or without modification, are permitted provided that the following conditions are met:\n\n1) Redistributions of source code must retain the above copyright notice, this list of conditions and the following disclaimer.\n\n2) Redistributions in binary form must reproduce the above copyright notice, this list of conditions and the following disclaimer in the documentation and/or other materials provided with the distribution.\n\nTHIS SOFTWARE IS PROVIDED BY THE COPYRIGHT HOLDERS AND CONTRIBUTORS \"AS IS\" AND ANY EXPRESS OR IMPLIED WARRANTIES, INCLUDING, BUT NOT LIMITED TO, THE IMPLIED WARRANTIES OF MERCHANTABILITY AND FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE ARE DISCLAIMED. IN NO EVENT SHALL THE COPYRIGHT HOLDER OR CONTRIBUTORS BE LIABLE FOR ANY DIRECT, INDIRECT, INCIDENTAL, SPECIAL, EXEMPLARY, OR CONSEQUENTIAL DAMAGES (INCLUDING, BUT NOT LIMITED TO, PROCUREMENT OF SUBSTITUTE GOODS OR SERVICES; LOSS OF USE, DATA, OR PROFITS; OR BUSINESS INTERRUPTION) HOWEVER CAUSED AND ON ANY THEORY OF LIABILITY, WHETHER IN CONTRACT, STRICT LIABILITY, OR TORT (INCLUDING NEGLIGENCE OR OTHERWISE) ARISING IN ANY WAY OUT OF THE USE OF THIS SOFTWARE, EVEN IF ADVISED OF THE POSSIBILITY OF SUCH DAMAGE.');
```

Comment: Maybe special characters you in data that you need to escape before inserting?

Comment: In addition there are column names with a space ex. `Full name` , that should be avoided and if really needed wrap them in backticks.

Comment: I don't have any problems executing your query in a test database. Show the table definitions.

Comment: @Alex, I have edited original questio nwith table definition. Please have a look and advise.

Answer (score 0):

In your `create table` the column `OSI Approved` has a space. Remove that space or escape it using backtique. Your create table should look like

```
CREATE TABLE licensetext_table (
LicenseId varchar(45) NOT NULL, 
FullName varchar(45) DEFAULT NULL,  
`OSI Approved` char(1) DEFAULT NULL,  
License_Text text, 
PRIMARY KEY (LicenseId)
)
```

Your `INSERT` statement accordingly should look like

```
INSERT INTO `licensetext_table` (`LicenseId`,`FullName`,`OSI Approved`,`License_Text`) 
VALUES ('BSD-2-Clause','BSD 2-clause \"Simplified\" License','Y','All rights ......'
```

See a successful DEMO Here http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/af95e1

Comment: I change the column name to OSIApproved, but no luck. Is there some thing wrong with big text?

Comment: @user3392184, are you sure about that? cause I don't think so. See the fiddle URL I have mentioned at last in my answer. Just change the `OSI Approved` column name in both `create` query and `insert` query and it should work just fine. Try the fiddle URL and see for urself.

Comment: I figured it out, there were brackets  ( and ) in big text, These need to escaped by \(, and \).

Comment: @user3392184, Good to know but I don't think the brackets `()` you are talking about are not preent in your posted code cause I didn't face them. Don't forget to accept the answer by clicking check button under voting button.